# Named Entity recognition

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am using stanford ner for removing the identity from the essays.

It is detecting the names like Werner..But indian names such as ram, shyam etc. goes undetected.

What i should do to make them recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

You should train NER for Indian names. I could not find detailed information for how to achieve that. But this FAQ page ( http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a ) has some information which may be a starting point for you. Especially the questions 2-3 are directly related to your question.

Comment: Information you provided was useful. But i dont want to train the classifier from beginning. I want to just add some indian names in the existing classifier file.